# Retrieve default browser search/find field text to be used in jquery

Tags: jquery, browser, full-text-search

I am using a js library (Perfect Scrollbar to be exact) to make a custom scrollbar on a website.

Since the overflow needs to be hidden in order for the custom scrollbars to show up, a lot of default functionality of the browser is disabled.

This includes the default find command for the browser.

I am familiar with `window.find()` methods, and I have seen other ideas for making a custom search form that sits on the webpage itself; however, I want to be able to retrieve the search text from the default browser search field in order to mimic the default search behavior of the browser, had I not used Perfect Scrollbar.

Is there a way for me to retrieve the search text (in jQuery say) if a user were to use `Ctrl+F`, `Ctrl+G`, or `window.find()` methods?

Edit: Let me clarify: The default find commands are still able to find text on a page, but the browser just does not scroll to the next match offset. If I can capture the search text in some way, I am planning on scrolling to each match manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get text from browser search control. And mimic default browser search functionality is really hard task to do. You will have to show your own popup window with text input where user will enter text to find (like in google docs), then search for text among visible elements (and it's not simple task to do), and, if found text is out of visible area, you should scroll elements with overflow:auto/scroll to show found text, etc...

Better way is using custom scrollbar that uses native browser scroll, so it will keep default browser scroll functions: scroll to focused element, scroll to search text, scroll to anchor (hash in url), etc... Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) or any scrollbar with **type:native** from this [scrollbar comparison table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was not aware of native scrollbar libraries vs. emulators. I decided to scrap the custom scrollbars, though, because I am not able to style every scrollbar element in the browser (like text areas) and I didn't want the website to look half-done.

Comment: Yeah, to apply custom scrollbar you should exactly know what elements should have it. The only way is to use CSS for webkit browsers, but IE and FF do not support it. Styling textarea scrollbar is more complex task and most of custom scrollbars does not support it, including jQuery Scrollbar.

Comment: I've updated jQuery Scrollbar and it supports styling textarea scrollbars now. Just for your interest :)